# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ComponentProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, class, generics, typescript-generics

i'm getting the following error when creating a High order component with TypeScript. Can you please help me solve this issue ?

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ComponentToWrapProps'
```

My code is the following:

Component:

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component<ILoginFormProps, ILoginFormState> {
 public render() {
  // JSX
 }
}

const enhance = compose(
 withFormHelpers,
 withStyles(styles)
)

export default enhance(LoginForm)
```

And HOC:

```
export interface IWithFormHelpersProps {}

export const withFormHelpers = <ComponentToWrapProps extends {}> 
 (ComponentToWrap: React.ComponentType<ComponentToWrapProps>) =>
   class WithFormHelpers extends React.Component<ComponentToWrapProps & IWithFormHelpersProps, {}> {
    public render() {
     return <>
      <ComponentToWrap />
     </>
    }

    onSubmitForm(event: React.FormEvent) {}

    onChangeInput(event: any) {}
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to supply `props` to your `ComponentToWrap`:

```
 <ComponentToWrap {...this.props} />
```

You cannot simply call `<ComponentToWrap />` here. It would work only if the knew `ComponentToWrap` will never receive any props. However, in your definition, you say it might receive some (`ComponentToWrapProps extends {}`). That's why we need to pass the props from the parent to the inner child.

Props will come from the parent and from `IWithFormHelpersProps`. Currently, `IWithFormHelpersProps` is empty, so everything you pass down is just `ComponentToWrapProps`.

However, if your `IWithFormHelpersProps` is going to have any properties (let's say `foo` and `bar`) then you should pick them out before spreading the rest of the props.

```
public render() {
 const { foo, bar, ...rest } = this.props;

 return <ComponentToWrap {...rest} />
}
```

Comment: It's working, but i wanted the hoc to give to the wrapped component only what he was expected (implemented in the hoc) and the hoc to accept other parameters. parent gives prop a,b to hoc and hoc gives to wrapped component c,d

Comment: So how would the HOC know the `props` it should pass down? Where are they coming from?

Comment: You can pass them manually.  I'm not sure but I think the main and only task of a hoc should be to add other props, so I think this task can be accomplished with other patterns....

Comment: The main objective is to create a wrapper that exposes as input prop "a" over a component with form elements and passes to it props "b" and "c" for example. The new created accepts "a" and the hoc gives to original component "b" and "c"